# Elasticsearch index not being created with settings from logstash template

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, aws-elasticsearch

I have a bulk upload for a new index that I'm sending to my ES cluster from logstash.  As such I want replication and refreshing turned off until the load is done, and I'll re-enable those values after the upload is complete.

I have a config file that looks like the following

```
input {
      stdin { type => stdin }
}
filter {
  csv {
     separator => " "
     columns => [ ...]
  }
}

output {
   amazon_es {
     hosts =>
         ["my-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
     index => "my-index"
     template => "conf/my-index-template.json"
     template_name => "my-index-template-name"
     region => "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

And the template file looks like

```
{
    "template" : "my-index-template-name",
    "mappings" : {
      ...
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "48",
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "refresh_interval": "-1"
      }
    }
}
```

And when I run logstash and go to look at the settings for that index, the mappings are all respected from this template which is good, but everything in the `settings` section is ignored and it takes on default values (i.e. `number_of_shards=5`, and `number_of_replicas=1`)

**Some investigation notes:**
If I get the template after it's installed from ES itself I see the proper values in the template (for both `mappings` and `settings`).  They just don't seem to be applying to the index

Also if I take the contents of the template file and create the index manually w/ a `PUT` it shows up as I would expect

My logstash version is 7.3.0 and my elasticsearch version is 6.7

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index name is `my-index`, but the template setting in your mapping uses `my-index-template-name`, it needs to be a regular expression or the same name as your index.

Since you are using elasticsearch 6.7 you should use `index_patterns` instead of `template` in your mapping.

```
{
    "index_patterns" : ["my-index"],
    "mappings" : {
      ...
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "48",
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "refresh_interval": "-1"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use `index_patterns` do I change the config file to use `index_patterns` instead of `template_name` as well?

Comment: No, the `index_patterns` is a setting in the elasticsearch mapping that defines to which index names that template will be applied, the `template_name` in logstash just defines the name for the template inside elasticsearch, it is basically the same as doing `PUT _template/template_name_value`.

Comment: I apologize, perhaps I didn't phrase my question properly.  If I change the template file to have an `index_patterns` entry as well, what should the logstash config look like in that case?

Comment: You can keep the same logstash configuration, there is no need to change, you can still use the `template` setting in your elasticsearch mapping, it has the same function as `index_patterns`, but it is deprecated in newer versions.